# How to clone a repo at a special revision and rename it with --depth=1 option?

Tags: git

I am actually cloning an app named `moodle` at revision `7223cd2` with:

```
git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:moodle/moodle.git 7223cd2
```

Then, I need to rename it manually :

```
mv 7223cd2 moodle
```

Is there a way to perform that with only one git command?

The following is not working:

```
git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:moodle/moodle.git 7223cd2 moodle
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:moodle/moodle.git 7223cd2
> ```

The above command is not cloning moodle at revision 7223cd2. It is cloning moodle into a folder named 7223cd2.

If the revision is a tag or a branch, you can clone it with:

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=<revision> <url/repo.git>
```

If the revision is a commit, I don't think you can do it out of the box with a single command.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below command:

```
git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:moodle/moodle.git 7223cd2 ; mv 7223cd2 moodle
```